# Custom Control - Why do I have a garbled Textblock visual artifact?

Tags: wpf, controls, textblock, artifact

I am developing a custom control in WPF/C# that involves a scale. The scale shows numeric labels (TextBlock instances) at key ticks along the scale as one would expect.

When doing some manual testing I came across a strange scenario where if I have just the right size of control a particular scale label becomes garbled.

Here is a link to a screenshot:

[image: screen shot of problem]

If I re-size the control a single pixel then it all works as expected.

Any idea what is happening? Is it just a WPF bug?

Comment: I've had weird things like this in windows too so it could be a graphics driver issue?

Comment: I would root for a font issue. Have you tried with a different font?